# multiple updates with a select?

Tags: sqlite, bulkinsert

i would like to write

```
insert into tbl1(a,b)
select 123, (select id from tbl2 where status=987)
```

the problem is, only one row is inserted instead of many rows. How do i fix this?
using Sqlite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not :

```
insert into tbl1(a,b)
select 123, id
  from tbl2
 where status = 987;
```

?

Answer (score 1):

did u try tis?

```
insert into tbl1(a,b)
select 123, x.*
  from (select id from tbl2 where status=987) x
```

Comment: Nested selects are useless here!